# Increase LimitRequestFieldsize apache 2.4.23 (Centos 7 using cpanel)

Tags: apache, cpanel, httpd.conf

I have been trying to change LimitRequestFieldsize however i am stuck in there. I tried putting value in /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf.

```
LimitRequestFieldsize 16380
```

But when i change it and rebuildhttpconf it gets removed. Please anyone can give me the proper procedure?? Thanks.

Comment: What is "rebuildhttpconf"? Do apachectl -t to syntax check, or just restart the server to make it take effect. If It's a cpanel thing it is offtopic here AFAIK.

Comment: rebuilding apache configuration it is the full command is /scripts/rebuildhttpdconf. this i used. Sorry i misspelled. This is apache thing.

Comment: I have httpd source and binaries right in front of me and I certainly don't have that rebuildhttpdconf thing anywhere, also checked all httpd official docs and it's not there either. You would be better off not using third-party scripts. Do as I suggested, configure and restart and try not to complicate so much such a simple thing as configuring and restarting or even do a syntax check with apache own scripts. Follow the official docs best: [LimitRequestFieldSize] (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize)